# Prove that the equation $\phi(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)! }\phi(t) dt $ have trivial solution for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Prove that the equation  $$\phi(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)! }\phi(t) dt $$ have trivial solution for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ in $C[0,\alpha]$

*Proof*

I want prove that exists a transformation $T:C[0,\alpha]\to C[0,\alpha]$ such that $T^{n}$ is contractil for conclude that $T$ have a unique fixed point say $x_0$ and conclude that $\phi(x_0)=x_0=0$.

For it I assume that $T_{n}(\phi(t))=\int_{0}^{x}\phi_{n-1}(t)dt$ and hence $T_{n}^{n}=\phi(x)$.

From here I need find $\gamma\in(0,1)$ such that $d(T(x)-T(y))\leq \gamma d(x,y)$.

Let $\phi_1(t),\phi_2(t)$arbitrary functions in $C[0,\alpha]$.

$$Sup_{x\in [0,\alpha]}=\left|\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)! }\phi_1(t) dt -\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)! }\phi_2(t) dt \right|=Sup_{x\in[0,\alpha]}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\left| \int_{0}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}(\phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t))dt\right|$$
From here I need bound it by $Sup_{x\in[0,\alpha]} |\phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t)|$.

Since $0\leq x\leq \alpha$ then $0 \leq x^n \leq \alpha^n$ and hence

from here I can´t continue but I think that $\gamma$ should be  $\gamma=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$.

Any advice for this proof?

Comment: can $\alpha$ be any positive real number?

Comment: Yes $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

Comment: I'm actually not sure it's necessarily true for $n=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the problem, we want to show that the solution is trivial for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in C[0,\alpha]$ and define
$$T_n\varphi=\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\varphi(t)dt$$
Note I will use $\|\cdot \|_\infty$ to denote the sup-norm on $[0,\alpha]$
and consider
$$\|T_n\varphi_1-T_n\varphi_2\|_\infty=\Big\|\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}(\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t))dt \Big\|_\infty$$
since $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in C[0,\alpha]$ we know they each obtain their supremums and you can move the absolute value inside the integral to get
$$\|T_n\varphi_1-T_n\varphi_2\|_\infty\leq\Big\|\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}|\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t)|dt \Big\|_\infty$$
$$\leq \|\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t)\|_\infty \Big\|\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt\Big\|_\infty$$

Now we compute $\Big\|\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt\Big\|_\infty$ directly
$$\Big\|\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}dt\Big\|_\infty=\Big\| \frac{x^n}{n!}\Big\|_\infty=\frac{\alpha^n}{n!}$$
Now, for every $n>1$ this says that $T_n$ is a contractive map and since the zero function satisfies the equation it must be the only solution.

Consider the case $n=1$ on your own.

Comment: In the last identity there should be an $\alpha^n$.

Comment: It seems this argument depends on $\alpha$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I misinterpret the problem

Comment: anytime @Juan T, maybe ask your professor to clarify the problem.  The $\alpha$ dependence is definitely an issue

Comment: Yes I think that is a typo and there should be $1$

Comment: @JuanT why would that be a typo? The problem doesn't ask to prove that $T_n$ is a contraction, it ask to prove that it has only a fixed point. There are other ways to do it, for instance, it's enough to prove that $T_n^k$ is a contraction for some $k > 0 $